# Animación en css aleatoria

Tags: javascript, css

estoy trasteando con js y me ha surgido la siguiente duda

Tengo divs creados con js, los cuales tienen la propiedad de posicion y tamaño aleatorios. Haciendolo de la siguiente forma.

Me gustaria saber cómo puedo hacer para que la animación de css se ejecute en un momento aleatorio para cada uno de los divs, y así no coincidan las animaciones a la vez, o si es mejor hacer esa animación con js

```js
var i = 0;
while (i < 300) {
    i++;
  
  var positionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
  var positionY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
  var size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  
  var estilo = "width:" + size + "px;height:" + size + "px;top:" + positionX + "%;left:" + positionY + "%;";
  
  
  var nuevoDiv = document.createElement("div");
  nuevoDiv.setAttribute("id", "div2");
  nuevoDiv.setAttribute("style", estilo);
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(nuevoDiv);
  
  }
```

```css
#div2{
  transition-duration:2s;
  position:absolute;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

@keyframes example {

    0% {transform: scale(0.1)}
    50% {transform: scale(1)}
    100% {transform: scale(.1)}
}
```

Dejo aquí en código completo con [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/Peluco/pen/JeMXMw)

Comment: podrías dentro del while validar si es par o impar , y dependiendo del resultado , asignarle la clase de animación que quieres para que te dé un resultado aleatorio

Answer (score 1):

Existe una propiedad de las animaciones que es `animation-delay` que te permite definir cuantos segundos de espera han de pasar para que se ejecute la animación.

Podrías tener establecidas varias clases **CSS** con animaciones que contengan esta propiedad con diferentes valores:

```
.animacion_1{
  transition-duration:2s;
  position:absolute;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.animacion_2{
  transition-duration:2s;
  position:absolute;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.animacion_3{
  transition-duration:2s;
  position:absolute;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-delay: 9s;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

@keyframes example {

    0% {transform: scale(0.1)}
    50% {transform: scale(1)}
    100% {transform: scale(.1)}
}
```

De esta manera, podrías luego generar un número aleatorio para elegir cual de estas tres clases le añades al elemento **HTML** en cuestión.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado facilmente gracias a @PHPMyguel con la idea de animation-delay

```js
var animationDelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  var animationDelay = animationDelay + "s";
  
  var estilo = "width:" + size + "px;height:" + size + "px;top:" + positionX + "%;left:" + positionY + "%;animation-delay:" + animationDelay;
```